# function calling of a structure error

Tags: c

I'm currently having problems trying to figure out the error of a certain part of the code that involves using a function that uses a structure of struct a and struct b

```
RectT a, b, recs[50];
int acount, bcount;
....

....
/* checks to see if the chk_overlap function returns a 1, if it does it adds 1 to bcount and acount */
if(chk_overlap(recs, a) == 1)
{
  bcount++;
}
if(chk_overlap(recs, b) == 1)
{
  acount++;
}
```

The function being called is

```
int chk_overlap(RectT *r1, RectT *r2){}
```

and the structure is

```
typedef struct rect
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int w;
  int h;
}RectT;
```

took off the code inside as this is a homework assignment

The current error is giving that im getting is

```
gcc -Wall -g -ansi -o xtst rec02.c
rec02.c: In function 'main':
rec02.c:64: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'chk_overlap'
rec02.c:69: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'chk_overlap'
```

Answer (score 2):

`chk_overlap()` accepts two `RectT *`. Thus, you could call it as

```
if(chk_overlap(recs, &a) == 1)
```

Note the `&` operator which takes the address of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You declared function to take pointers to that structure, but in code, you are trying to pass not pointer, but structrure itself, as a value.
You should call:

```
chk_overlap(recs, &b)
```